# Azure Analysis Service asynchronous refresh through REST API call not working when only refreshing certain tables / partitions

Tags: azure, azure-analysis-services

I am trying to refresh an Analysis Service through the REST API documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-async-refresh

When I do a full refresh of the whole model by sending this data:

```js
{'Type': 'Full', 'CommitMode': 'transactional'}
```

in the POST request, everything works.

The model refreshes and after polling for the status for a while I finally get this response:

```js
{'startTime': '2019-12-09T09:50:28.4905312Z', 
 'endTime': '2019-12-09T10:51:21.614713Z', 
 'type': 'full', 
 'status': 'succeeded', 
 'currentRefreshType': 'full', 
 'objects': [
   {'table': 'Advertiser', 'partition': 'Partition', 'status': 'succeeded'}, 
   ...
   {'table': 'Delivery', 'partition': '201901', 'status': 'succeeded'}, 
   {'table': 'Delivery', 'partition': '201902', 'status': 'succeeded'},
   ...
   {'table': 'Delivery', 'partition': '201911', 'status': 'succeeded'}, 
   {'table': 'Delivery', 'partition': '201912', 'status': 'succeeded'},
   ...
   {'table': 'OrderType', 'partition': 'Partition', 'status': 'succeeded'}
 ]}
```

But this model is pretty big and I'd like to only refresh the last 2 months of the Delivery table.

Following the documentation I send this in the POST request:

```js
{'Type': 'full', 
 'CommitMode': 'transactional'
 'Objects': [
   {'table': 'Delivery', 'partition': '201912'}, 
   {'table': 'Delivery', 'partition': '201911'}
 ]}
```

But now I immediately get this response:

```js
{'startTime': '2019-12-10T08:09:17.6665594Z', 
 'endTime': '2019-12-10T08:09:18.5620142Z', 
 'type': 'full', 
 'status': 'failed', 
 'currentRefreshType': 'full', 
 'objects': [
   {'status': 'failed'}, 
   {'status': 'failed'}, 
   {'status': 'failed'}, 
   {'status': 'failed'}], 
 'messages': [
   {'message': "The specified table '(null)' not found in the target model.", 'type': 'error'}
]}
```

I've tried it with different tables (with or without specifying the partitions), different partitions etc. but always get this same error message.

I don't understand that the tables are found when doing a full refresh but not when doing refresh on a specific table?

Comment: have you found any solution besides sending query per table?

Answer (score 2):

Iexperienced the same problem. You should execute two POST requests, like this:

```
{'Type': 'full', 
 'CommitMode': 'transactional'
 'Objects': [
   {'table': 'Delivery', 'partition': '201912'}
 ]}

{'Type': 'full', 
 'CommitMode': 'transactional'
 'Objects': [
   {'table': 'Delivery', 'partition': '201911'}
 ]}
```

I know it's not the best solution but it is worth  a try.

Comment: is there any alternative now? I would like to refresh by partition, but don't want to send 20-30 queries

Answer (score 0):

You can add the partitions and tables to refresh like below:

```
{
  "CommitMode": "transactional",
  "MaxParallelism": 2,
  "Objects": [
    {
      "partition": "FACT_Sale_Daily FY12",
      "table": "FACT_Sale_Daily"
    },
    {
      "partition": "FACT_Sale_Daily FY13",
      "table": "FACT_Sale_Daily"
    },
    {
      "table": "DIM_Currency"
    },
    {
      "table": "DIM_Date"
    },
    {
      "table": "DIM_LoyaltyType"
    },
    {
      "table": "DIM_Merch"
    },
    {
      "table": "DIM_Store"
    },
    {
      "table": "DIM_Store_Comp"
    },
    {
      "table": "DIM_Store_Comp2"
    },
    {
      "table": "ETL_Date"
    }
  ],
  "RetryCount": 2,
  "Type": "Full"
}
```